# WooCommerce Save Custom Product Field on Quick Edit

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How Can I save my custom Product field value in the admin area of WooCommerce using the Quick Edit button/function?

I have initialized a custom product field here called 'amazon_asin':

```
function bh_amazon_custom_asin_meta() {
    $args = array(
     'label' => __( 'Amazon ASIN', 'woocommerce' ),
    'placeholder' => __( 'Enter Amazon ASIN value here', 'woocommerce' ),
    'id' => 'amazon_ASIN',
    'desc_tip' => true,
    'description' => __( 'This meta box is for internal only. Please add ASIN value here', 'woocommerce' ),
    );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_sku', 'bh_amazon_custom_asin_meta');

function bh_amazon_custom_asin_save ( $post_id ) {
    //grab the custom ASIN box
    if ( isset( $_POST[ 'amazon_ASIN' ] ) ) {
    $asin = isset( $_POST[ 'amazon_ASIN' ] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'amazon_ASIN' ] ) : '';
    }

    // grab the product
  $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    // save the custom ASIN meta field
  $product->update_meta_data( 'amazon_ASIN', $asin );
  $product->save();

}

add_action ( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'bh_amazon_custom_asin_save');
```

I then populated this field in the product section. The value can be seen here in quick edit using this code:

```
add_action('quick_edit_custom_box',  'brians_quick_edit_fields', 10, 2);

function brians_quick_edit_fields( $column_name, $post_type ) {

    $asin = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'amazon_ASIN', true );


switch( $column_name ) :
        case 'featured': {

echo '<fieldset class="inline-edit-col-right"><div class="inline-edit-col"><div class="inline-edit-group wp-clearfix">';

            echo '<label class="alignleft">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="featured">
                    <span class="checkbox-title">Featured product</span>
                </label>';


            break;

        }

    case 'asin': {
            echo '<label class="alignleft">
                    <span class="title">Amazon Asin</span>';    
                    echo '<span class="input-text-wrap"><input type="text" name="amazon" value="' . $asin .'"></span>
                </label>';


            // for the LAST column only - closing the fieldset element
            echo '</div></div></fieldset>';

            break;

        }

    endswitch;

}
```

Admin panel where current value is shown:

[image: Admin panel where current value is shown]

But when I attempt to update or save a new value using the quick edit function, the post does not update:

```
/*
 * Quick Edit Save
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_bulk_and_quick_edit', 'brians_quick_edit_save', 10, 2 );

function brians_quick_edit_save( $column_name, $post_type ){

    // update the ASIN
    if ( isset( $_POST['amazon_ASIN'] ) ) {
        echo 'this is set';
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'amazon_ASIN', $_POST['amazon_ASIN'] );
    }
}
```

For some reason `isset( $_POST['amazon_ASIN'] )` returns `null` or `false`. What can I do to successfully update and save this value using quick edit?

Comment: You forgot `switch` before the first `case` on `brians_quick_edit_fields()` function…

Comment: Oops. Missed that while copying my code over, I have updated it here but it does not solve the original question. Thank you though!

Comment: As per your above bulk action form field code, it seems you have added `"amazon"` as in name field. So try to fetch data with checking `isset( $_POST['amazon'] )` in bulk save callback.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I have tried this as well already. isset( $_POST['amazon'] ) returns null. As does something like isset( $_POST['price'] ), which I believed was a set WooCommerce meta field. So I am not sure how to proceed.